# what happens if I initialise the same property multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initialization, swift2

I am declaring a property in a class:

```
var testView: UIView!
```

later on, I initialise it with with the following code:

```
testView = UIView(frame: myFrame)
```

But than, later on, I initialise it again:

```
testView = UIView(frame: myFrame)
```

What happend with the first testView instance? Is testView now using twice the memory? What happens if I repeat this process a 1000 times? Am I allowed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift and Object C use [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) memory management.

Unless you are referencing the first UIview elsewhere, on the successive assignment to testView the first UIView reference count will become 0 and its memory will be freed.

So testView will always use the memory needed for one UIView, even if you repeat the process 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will just overwrite the values. You can do it 1000 times, but its pointless. It just cost some CPU capacity.

> Every time you create a new instance of a class, ARC allocates a chunk of memory to store information about that instance. This memory holds information about the type of the instance, together with the values of any stored properties associated with that instance.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 1):

Just like if I reinitialize a string to a different value, the original value is replaced, so if I assign the string to the same value as the old value it is replaced, with that in mind when you reassign the `UIView` to the same value the old value is replaced. Why do you need to replace the old value with the same value?

Comment: Like @mario zannone mentioned, Swift and Objective-C use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), which will take care of all that happens to initialization to your properties, if you were using Objective-C from iOS4 on the other hand, you would have to manage that.